# EF Core cannot translate lambda containing .ANY() built with expression tree

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

A bit of context:
I have a generic filtering built with reflection and expression trees that, based on a path to the property desired to be fitlered on, it returns a lambda that can be used against an IQueryable.

Let's say we have two classes:

```
public class ParkingLot {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car {
    public virtual ParkingLot ParkingLot { get; set; }
    public int ParkingLotId { get; set; }
    public bool IsHybrid { get; set; }
}
```

At this point i want to filter all the Parking lots based on the IsHybrid property.
I would do something like

```
var query = parkingLotsQueryable.Where(pk => pk.Cars.Any(c => c.IsHybrid));
```

Well this works as intended and it's executed and translated into SQL with no problems. My filtering service would also return for this specific scenario the same
`pk => pk.Cars.Any(c => c.IsHybrid)`. But using this against the dataset inside an Where method return me an error that it cannot be translated to sql.

The error would be:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Cars>()
    .Where(t0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: ParkingLot
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
        IsNullable: True
    , "Id") != null && object.Equals(
        objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
            EntityType: ParkingLot
            ValueBufferExpression: 
                ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
            IsNullable: True
        , "Id"), 
        objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t0, "ParkingLotId")))
    .Any(t0 => c.IsHybrid)' could not be translated.
```

Writing this I realized that when it applies .Any() it actually doesn't use the correct paramater as in "t0 => c.IsHybrid". Doubled-checking the service, it actually uses the correct types when generating those parameters, so I actually have no idea why EF Core screws me so much and at this point I think I'm too dived in to see the answer.

Also, inspecting the query after applying the Where condition in DebugMode I can find an expression that doesn't seem to contain anything "not translatable":
`DbSet<ParkingLot>().Where(pk => pk.Cars.Any(c => c.IsHybrid))`

Comment: We need to see how you are generating the expression tree.

Comment: That's a rather long class :)) if there was a problem when generating the expression, shouldn't it fail at compile time?

Comment: Well you are telling us there's a problem with your expression without showing us the expression.

Comment: Usually there is problem with parameters. Parameters are equal only by reference, not name and type.

Comment: The error you are showing indicates an expression that doesn't match the one you are showing - it is testing against `null` and against `Id.Equals(ParkingLotId)`.

Comment: @MrExpression *"if there was a problem when generating the expression, shouldn't it fail at compile time?"* It will, but there is **no** compilation time when you build expression. Compilation time is if you call `.Compile()` on the generated lambda expression. And you'll definitely get an error because apparently something is wrong with the `ParameterExpression` instances. Nnote that the name of the parameters, i.e. what you see in the debug window, doesn't matter - you can name all parameter expressions let say "x"  and they'll still be different. So you can see e.g. `(x, x) => x + x` :)

Comment: @MrExpression So, as many others commented, the problem is with the method generating the expression. Either provide it (long or not) so we can pinpoint the problematic code, or check the `ParameterExpression` (and `Expression.Invoke`) usages yourself.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you! I decided to solve it in a non generic way for the moment due to time issues, but I will definitely look in to it the next week or so in a standalone project. 
Just to get it right,  even if in my case t0 != c, the t0 => c.IsHybrid should work because the naming doesn't matter. Am i correct?
I will look into it myself some more time and post the progress or(hopefully) the correct answer

Comment: The naming doesn't matter, but EF Core output `t0 => c.IsHybrid` clearly indicates that there is something wrong. I mean, sometimes you could see `c => c.isHybrid` where first `c` and second `c.` are *different* expressions. Your case is different because you visually see they are different. `t0` seems to be from EFC doing navigation property `pk.Cars` expansion (replacing it the corresponding sub query), but why it is used inside the `.Any` call is unknown. Again, most probably some part of your code is generating something which later is confusing EF Core processor and leads to the error.